# hive : select row with column having maximum value without join

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

writing hive query over a table to pick the row with maximum value in column
there is table with following data for example:

```
key    value    updated_at
  1    "a"      1  
  1    "b"      2  
  1    "c"      3
```

the row which is updated last needs to be selected.
currently using following logic

```
select tab1.* from table_name tab1
join select tab2.key , max(tab2.updated_at) as max_updated from table_name tab2
on tab1.key=tab2.key and tab1.updated_at = tab2.max_updated;
```

Is there any other better way to perform this?

Comment: Is the value for `updated_at` unique in that table?

Comment: Also, which version of Hive are you using?  The query you posted doesn't appear to be valid HiveQL to me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is true that `updated_at` is unique for that table, then the following is perhaps a simpler way of getting you what you are looking for:

```
-- I'm using Hive 0.13.0
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY updated_at DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If it is possible for `updated_at` to be non-unique for some reason, you may need to adjust the `ORDER BY` logic to break any ties in the fashion you wish.